# Simulate a binomial distribution experiment

Tags: function-construction, probability-or-statistics

I am trying to write a user-defined function to simulate a binomial experiment as following:

```
binominalRV[n_, p_] = Count[
  Table[RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[]], n]
  , x_/; (x < p)]
```

Entering `binominalRV[10000,0.5]` outputs `0`, which is far away from the expectation(~`5000`):

With the following command:

```
Count[
  Table[RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[]], 10000]
```

I got `4997`, which is reasonable. Is there anything  wrong with the function definition?

Comment: You need to use `SetDelayed` rather than `Set`

Comment: You can also explore the functionality provided by  `NProbability[x <= 0.5, x \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RandomVariate` can generate a list of `n` values. There is no need for a `Table`.

```
binominalRV[n_, p_] := 
 Count[RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[], n], x_ /; (x < p)]

binominalRV[10000, 0.5]
```

> 4942